# check a value in a datafram match a string in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to check whether a value in a specific row and column match exactly a string in a list (Please consider that I am looking for the exact matching).

```
#input data
mylist_tram = ["VBZ_line9", "VBZ_line8"]

#data frame _ df
ActivityType_EOD    lineId_EOD
leg                 AAG_line7
leg                 AAG_line50
leg                 VBZ_line9
leg                 VBZ_line8
```

I have written the following code but it is not correct

```
#check the value in data frame for matching
df[df.loc[2, 'lineId_EOD'] in mylist_tram]
```

the expected output is a False or True answer.

I cannot use `isin()`
such as

```
df.loc[2, 'lineId_EOD'].isin(mylist_tram)
```

because I have the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: if you need exact match, `df[col].isin(yourlist)`

Comment: @Datanovice  it is not possible because I got the error:'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Comment: @sahel - There is some error? Because it should working nice.

Comment: `df.loc[2, 'lineId_EOD'] in ["VBZ_line9", "VBZ_line8"]` is working just fine. What is the output (or error if any) you are getting?

Comment: @jezrael,, true, it works fine. I have written it with other code in one line and that cause the error. However, just for the line that I have written here, it works completely fine

Comment: @Chris, , true, it works fine. I have written it with other code in one line and that cause the error. However, just for the line that I have written here, it works completely fine

Comment: @sahel - OK, so issue solved?

Comment: @jezrael yes, it is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because compare scalar output of selected value of `DataFrame` get `True` or `False` scalar:

```
out = df.loc[2, 'lineId_EOD'] in mylist_tram
```

Answer (score 0):

`df[df.loc[2, 'lineId_EOD'] in mylist_tram]`

should change to

`df.loc[2, 'lineId_EOD'] in mylist_tram`